# How do I access the value of a node reference field from PHP code used in a view contextual filter?

Tags: 7, views

How do I return the value of a node reference field via PHP code in a view contextual filter?

I am attempting to do so via the following steps:

- Adding the node reference field in the contextual filters area
- Selecting "PHP Code" under "Provide default value"

I get stuck here because none of the data items provided by the Views module (`$view` and `$argument`) give access to the data saved in the node reference field.

In Drupal 6, the Views module gives access to a `$data` variable which contains CCK data saved in nodes, but it seems there is nothing like that in Drupal 7.